# No smb.conf file after installing samba 4.0.9

Tags: samba

Samba won't start and I've done 'locate smb.conf' but it can't be found. I cd'd to '/usr/local/samba/etc/' and not in '/etc/samba/' either. The samba path in in '/etc/environment' so I can start samba with 'service samba4 start' but it won't start. How can I repair this problem? Can I just copy a smb.conf from another samba server?

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem and an error report eventually came up which identified my situation exactly - I had done;

1. `sudo apt-get remove samba --purge`
2. `sudo apt-get autoremove`
3. manually deleted contents of `/etc/samba` including `smbd.conf`
4. reinstalled samba

What I did NOT do but should have done before reinstalling samba was

```
sudo apt-get purge samba-common
```

If you do this, then reinstall, the samba directory and conf file will be reinstalled.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. Why is it so complicated :-).

Answer (score 1):

I have two of these files in /etc/samba/ and /usr/share/samba/.  Investigate if you have all the appropriate samba packages installed.  Mine are installed from the Ubuntu distribution using apt-get.

Also the locate is not necessarily inclusive of the entire filesystem.  Use `find` if you want to search everything.

Comment: +1 for the `find` command !

Comment: I installed samba from source. 'Find' did not give any result, but locate did.

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/samba.html) does a really great job of explaining how to install Samba 4.0.9 including the step(s) to create /etc/samba/smb.conf.

Comment: I will read through it and see if it gives me a better solution to the wiki-page I used during install. This is the guide I used: http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/HOWTO/Join_a_domain_as_a_DC

Comment: By installing samba from source, it gets installed in /usr/local/samba/. I haven't installed from repository. I did ./configure --enable-debug --enable-selftest
make
make install

Comment: Have you verified that /usr/local/samba is in your PATH? `echo $PATH`  Also, have you created the /etc/init.d script for samba4?

Comment: Yes it is in PATH
root@dc01:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/samba/bin:/usr/local/samba/sbin

I have created the script for automatic start of samba4, yes.

Comment: smb.conf was missing in samba 4.0.9
I solved it by copying the content of DC01 and pasted it in a new smb.conf file on dc02, changed the netbios name in smb.conf to dc02. Then I used samba-tool domain join to add it as an additional domain controller. I started samba and it was working. They replicate between eachother